# Master-detail segue from DetailViewController with back button

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, uisplitviewcontroller, master-detail

I am using the Master-Detail template. I would like to know the best way to segue from the detail view to 'more detail' view and keep the back button? 
[image]

I am currently using the 'Show Detail (e.g. Replace)' segue. This works for iPhone, as when I tap on a button in the detail view, and segue to my 'more detail, there is a 'Detail' button in the left bar button, which takes me back to the detail view. For iPad the back button isn't there.

IPhone (works as expected):

[image]

IPad with split view, missing '< Detail' button:

[image]

The behaviour I want is like the Messages app on the iPad. The master shows a list of conversations, the detail view shows the selected conversation, and there is a Details button in the top right bar button. Tapping on it replaces the conversation view with a Find my Friends view, and there is a bar button to take you back to the conversation.

Update:
[image]

Comment: Looks like the iPad thinks that its your root view?

Comment: In my DetailViewController in prepareForSegue I am doing moreDetailsViewController *controller = (moreDetailsViewController *)[[segue destinationViewController] topViewController]; Is this where I'm going wrong? Is that what you mean? Thanks.

Comment: That could be the issue. Someone else with more split view experience will be able to provide a better answer but I think iPad handles these split views a little differently than the iPhone. Since both paths already have a navigation controller, perhaps try moving that joining segue from the nav controller to controller you want to present directly. Does that make sense?

Comment: Thanks, I'll investigate that. I did try removing the navigation controller between the detail and moreDetail controllers but didn't seem to have any effect.

Answer (score 1):

There are two different Bar Button items a back Button and an "expand" button.

The Back button is useful for going back if the device is an iPhone. On iPad you don't need the back button, at least in the screen you showed, in detail view with overlay master, because the master table is still visible and you can easily change the content of the detailview by clicking in the table.
But there is also an expand button, it will hide the mastertable and expand the detail view to to spread from one edge to the other.

```
splitViewController!.preferredDisplayMode = UISplitViewControllerDisplayMode.AllVisible
```

This will show both master and detail

change .AllVisible to PrimaryHidden, Automatic or PrimaryOverlay and see the behavior.

You can prepare the button in prepare for segue at the MasterView.

```
 controller.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = self.splitViewController?.displayModeButtonItem()
 controller.navigationItem.leftItemsSupplementBackButton = true 
 controller.title = "Title of Detailview" // Set title of Detailview Master has own
 controller.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem?.title = "back" // Backbutton Title is set to "back instead of Title of Masterview //
```

Comment: My problem is that the view I'm showing in the screenshots is not the detail view but another subview, segued to by tapping on a field in the detail view, so I do need the back button in the iPad. If you look at my storyboard at the top, I want to go from the far right back to the detail view in the standard master-detail template.

Comment: Hi Matt, how do you get to that far right view? Using prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) if yes how do you init the viewController?  `let controller = (segue.destinationViewController as! UINavigationController).topViewController as! DetailViewController`?

Comment: Hi. I have a segue linked from the detailView to the moreDetailView. It is a 'Show Detail (e.g. Replace)' as I just want to replace the detail, keeping the master table in the left side of the view. I want the back button to undo this, as works for iPhone. I've updated my question with an annotated storyboard if that helps explain what I mean. Thanks for the help.

Comment: In my detailViewController, in the prepareForSegue, I do `MoreDetailViewController *controller = (MoreDetailViewController *)[[segue destinationViewController] topViewController];`

Comment: if you don't need the System Button (expand) you can use this for showing a button: `controller.navigationItem.leftItemsSupplementBackButton = true
                let cancleButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.Cancel, target: self, action: "cancleButton:")
                controller.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem? = cancleButton`@matt_s

Comment: @matt_s: You can also set the Buttons in viewDidLoad of MoreDetailViewController it depends where you want to handle the action. add this to viewDidLoad `let button = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.Cancel, target: self, action: "someOtherAction")`
        `let addbutton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.Add, target: self, action: "someOtherAction")
        self.navigationItem.setLeftBarButtonItems([button, addbutton], animated: true)` then you ll have two buttons (left) an add and a cancle button